# Position in file of a particular value

Tags: c

I have a C binary file with 512<sup>3</sup> values in the form of a 3-dimensional cube. I need to access the position in the cube with the highest value, which is the density. Once I have the position of the highest value, I need to create a smaller 3D cube about this position with values that are obviously smaller than 512 (the dimension of the cube). `start` represents the position at one corner of the smaller cube. `p` is the binary file obviously.

```
fseek(p,0,SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell(p);
rewind(p);

dim = pow(lSize/sizeof(float),1.0/3.0);
printf("File size: %lu bytes, Grid size: %d \n", lSize,(int)dim);

max = 0;
counter = 0;
index = 0;
while(fread(&density,sizeof(float),1,p),!feof(p) && !ferror(p)) {
  if(density > max) max = density,index = counter;
  counter += 1;
}

sub = 256;
start = index - (pow(dim,2)+dim+1)*(sub/2-1);
printf("3d coordinates of highest density: %lu,%lu,%lu, Dimension of cube: %d\n",index % 512;(index / 512) % 512;index / (512 * 512),(int)dim);

printf("The maximum density is: %e with index: %lu \n", max,index); 

rewind(p);
fseek(p,start*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
fseek(q,start*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
fseek(r,start*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
fseek(s,start*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
fseek(t,start*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);

u = fopen("results_dens.dat", "w");
if (u == NULL) { printf("Unable to open output results file!"); exit(1); }

for (ibox=0;ibox<nbox;ibox++){
  for (k=0;k<nz[ibox];k++){
    fseek(p,(start+k*dim*dim)*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
    fseek(q,(start+k*dim*dim)*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
    fseek(r,(start+k*dim*dim)*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
    fseek(s,(start+k*dim*dim)*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
    fseek(t,(start+k*dim*dim)*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
    for (j=0;j<ny[ibox];j++){
      fseek(p,(start+j*dim+k*dim*dim)*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
      fseek(q,(start+j*dim+k*dim*dim)*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
      fseek(r,(start+j*dim+k*dim*dim)*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
      fseek(s,(start+j*dim+k*dim*dim)*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
      fseek(t,(start+j*dim+k*dim*dim)*sizeof(float),SEEK_SET);
       for (i=0;i<nx[ibox];i++){
```

I am aware that the above code runs without any errors. However, a lot rides on the value of `index` above. I am unsure of how positions are defined in C. I am aware that these are memory locations but by doing some rough calculations, the value of index that I derive seems to be close to the edge of the box and not the centre.

512<sup>3</sup> = 134217728.
The value of `index` is 66978048, 130816 positions from the middle position value of 67108864. But, 130816 is approximately 512*256 meaning that if the middle position of the grid is at the edge of the box, then so is `index` above.

Comment: Don't use the result of `feof` or `ferror` to control the termination of your loop. Use the result returned by `fread`. You can use `feof()` or `ferror()` after the loop terminates to find out why it terminated.

Comment: It runs without error Keith. Those are just safety checks, but thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If it compiles without error, the *syntax* is correct. Do you possibly mean "algorithm"?

Comment: You're still using the result of `feof()` and `ferror()` to control the termination of the loop. You're ignoring the value returned by `fread()`. I *think* what you're doing should work, but I stand by my advice.

Comment: @Keith - I completely agree with your advice, and shall employ it in the future.

Comment: @Jongware - I do mean algorithm!

Comment: Use `dim*dim` i/o `pow(dim,2)`, and represent `dim` as integer, it's slightly quicker and in general you don't want to use float arithmetics to calculate position in a file.

Comment: Were it me, I'd want to convert the `index` value into the 3D equivalent (calculate the x, y, z indices from the sequential offset). I don't see code to do that (`z = index % 512; y = (index / 512) % 512; x = index / (512 * 512);`, I think). Printing the coordinates would tell whereabouts in the cube the densest point is To create a smaller 3D cube about that point, you'd need to read the appropriate subsets of the data. If you want an NxNxN cube (N odd), then you'd have to read N values at a time from each of NxN starting positions, and write them out in the correct sequence to the new file.

Comment: In fact, using my formulae for x, y, z with index 66978048 reveals a position (255,256,256), which is pretty close to the centre of a 512x512x512 cube, no matter how you slice and dice it.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I will try that. Should there be an additional % 512 in the calculation for x?

Comment: You can use `x = (index / (512 * 512)) % 512;` (it does no harm), but if the index is in range, the division will yield a value 0..511 anyway.

Comment: @Jonathan - well I am not an expert in C but that would be a huge relief, I have been working on a project for a year assuming I was catching a position close to the centre. I have included additional code above, which I implemented to access x,y,z locations in the form of a for-loop for the 3D box. I am sure that it does the job, but there is a slight chance I could be incorrect.

Comment: Ignore q,r,s, and t. They are merely other binary files produced similarly to p.

Comment: So you're going to be reading from 5 files (file streams `p`..`t`)?  Note that there's no point in doing rewinds or `fseek(..., SEEK_SET)` followed by another `fseek(..., SEEK_SET)`; the final seek controls the position for the read.  I would probably write a function to pull a sub-range from a single file, and then call that 5 times, rather than writing everything out 5 times (repetition in the source indicates you've not written it correctly, usually).

Comment: In the most general case, you'd need a function interface such as `int extract_subcube(FILE *in, FILE *out, int x0, int x1, int xmax, int y0, int y1, int ymax, int z0, int z1, int zmax);` where the max parameters would be 512 in your current case, and the x0 and x1 integers would be the range of x-values to be included in the output, etc.  In fact, I'd probably create a structure to hold the triples (`struct range { int lo; int hi; int max; };`) and another to hold three of those (`struct cuboid { struct range x; struct range y; struct range z; };`).

Comment: Then the function can become `int extract_cuboid(FILE *in, FILE *out, struct cuboid *shape);`.  Etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57949/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-stars83clouds).

Comment: But I am reading from individual binary files. Don't you need separate statements, at least at first, to access each individual file? The syntax is lazy, I know, but would it be correct from your experience? Each time, it accesses the file from the first location and moves to however many positions are required. Time consuming, I know, but is it erroneous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will help.  First, I created a test file with the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int makeCube(const char *fn, int dim)
{
    FILE *p;

    const int center = dim/2;
    p = fopen(fn,"w");
    for (int i=0; i < dim; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j < dim; ++j)
        for (int k=0; k < dim; ++k) {
            float f = dim - sqrtf(pow(i-center,2)+
                                  pow(j-center,2)+pow(k-center,2));
            fwrite(&f, sizeof(float), 1, p);
        }
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}
int main() 
{
    const int dim = 512;
    makeCube("cube.bin", dim);
    return 0;
}
```

Next I rewrote your code to have correct syntax and to print some diagnostics which seemed useful:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int subCube(FILE *p, int dim)
{
    float density;
    float max = 0;
    long index = 0;
    long counter;

    for (counter=0; fread(&density,sizeof(float),1,p); ++counter) {
        if(density > max) {
            max = density;
            index = counter;
        }
    }

    printf("The maximum density is: %e with index: %lu \n", max,index); 
    int i = index/dim/dim;
    int j = (index - (i*dim*dim))/dim;
    int k = (index - ((i*dim)+j)*dim);
    printf("This corresponds to coordinates (%d,%d,%d)\n", i,j,k);
}

int main() 
{
    const int dim = 512;
    FILE *p = fopen("cube.bin","r");
    subCube(p, dim);
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run that program, I get the following output:

```
The maximum density is: 5.120000e+02 with index: 67240192 
This corresponds to coordinates (256,256,256)
```

Since the test data was basically a sphere with greatest density at the middle, this is exactly as expected.

Note that I have played fast and loose with error handling (there isn't any!) but it's omitted for clarity and not because you should actually omit it in a real program.